# Search for “whole word match” in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I want search the exact word using select query in mysql

eg: My table column content

```
"This is a sample mail to test Auto Decline Invitation."
```

Qry:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` where text REGEXP '[[:<:]]Invitation.[[:>:]]'
```

In above example i need to select all records match with **'Invitation.'**

Comment: Use `REGEXP '[[:<:]]Invitation[.]'`. Or, is it MySQL v8?

Comment: What is the version of MySQL?

Comment: Switch to a `FULLTEXT` index and use `MATCH(text) AGAINST('+invitation' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew version is 5.7.31

Comment: Good, so `REGEXP '[[:<:]]Invitation[.]'` will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you so much. I got exact word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `REGEXP`, you could also use the [`LIKE` pattern matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) operator.

A sample query could be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `text` LIKE '%Invitation.%';
```

---

**Edit**

Otherwise, if `LIKE` doesn't match your requirements, you can of course use `REGEXP`.

For a `REGEXP` (MySQL 5.7) expression, you'll want to use (mentioned by [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew)):

```sql
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `text` REGEXP '[[:<:]]Invitation[.]';
```

For a `REGEXP` (MySQL 8.0) expression, you'll want to use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `text` REGEXP '\\bInvitation\\.';
```

The `[[:<:]]` & `[[:>:]]`, and `\b` operators offer similar functionality for their boundaries. MySQL 5.7 is a little bit more explicit, as you can see per the [documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) at the bottom of the page. With MySQL 8.0, it supports the International Components for Unicode (ICU), as opposed to 5.7 that uses Henry Spencer's implementation for regular expressions.

From the [MySQL 8.0 docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html):

> MySQL implements regular expression support using International Components for Unicode (ICU), which provides full Unicode support and is multibyte safe. (Prior to MySQL 8.0.4, MySQL used Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions, which operates in byte-wise fashion and is not multibyte safe.

If you do a search on this documentation page for `\b`, you'll see some clarification between the difference of ICU vs. Spencer regular expression handling:

> The Spencer library supports word-beginning and word-end boundary markers (`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` notation). ICU does not. For ICU, you can use `\b` to match word boundaries; double the backslash because MySQL interprets it as the escape character within strings.

*Bit of a learning experience for me too, thanks Wiktor!*

Comment: I need exact word. I'm working with dynamically word search. the 'LIKE' is  not good for using exact word search.

Comment: I see, I've updated my answer. It is probably tripping up on your query because of the dot (`.`) in your expression.

Comment: `'[[:<:]]Invitation[.][[:>:]]'` is wrong. The `.` is not a word character.

Comment: But the permissible character names given on the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) shows that a period/full stop is delimited by its own character, or I may be understanding it incorrectly. I've updated my answer with a MySQL v8 version too.

Comment: Now, your patterns for 5.7 and 8.0 versions differ. Actually, the second `\b` is redundant in your last pattern. Please explain that to OP.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your feedback! I've updated my answer with some follow-up documentation & notes as to the differences between 5.7 and 8.0, and also remove the redundant boundary on the 8.0 example, and made each pattern the same (hopefully?).

Comment: @BipinSV Did the adjustments to my answer help you come to a solution?

Comment: @Reece yes I implemented in query. Now need to help to find out that match word in PHP preg_replace_callback function. How can be find 'Invitation.'  exact word from a sentence?  I need to highlight that word.